# Deleting a specific set of content from txt file with php

Tags: php, file, magento

I need some advise please...

Once an order is placed on my Magento store, I have an observer that looks at the event and triggers the txt file to be generated with the order info.

A GPRS printer then looks at this txt file every 50sec and prints the order.

This is the format of one order in the txt file:

```
# 10 *1*100000190*1;Ice Cream; 15; 1;Coke; 8; 1;Chicken Burger; 33; *15*n/a;71; 4;John Doe;1 test street, City;08:01 13-12-2013; 184;7; n/a;011123123;*#
```

(Note the "100000190" is the unique order number)

Once the order has been printed, it can be Accepted/Rejected by the operator. The Accept/Reject confirmation will then be send feedback from the printer to a different php file on the server. (This confirmation will again contain the unique order number)

Once the Accept/Reject confirmation has been received the order should be deleted from the original txt file so as to not be read and processed/printed again.

So there will be multiple orders going into the txt file so I can't simply clear the content when I receive the confirmation of one order as the other orders will then be lost.

How will i go about only deleting the order that was confirmed from the txt file and leaving the rest?

Here is an example of the txt file containing 3 orders:

---

# 10 *1*100000190*1;Ice Cream; 15; 1;Coke; 8; 1;Chicken Burger; 33; *15*n/a;71; 4;John Doe;1 test street, City;insert time attribute; 184;7; n/a;011123123;*## 10 *1*100000191*1;Ice Cream; 15; 1;Chicken Wrap; 33; *15*n/a;63; 4;John Doe;1 test street, City;insert time attribute; 185;7; n/a;011123123;*## 10 *2*100000192*1;Chicken Wrap; 33; *0*n/a;33; 4;John Doe;1 test street, City;insert time attribute; 186;7; n/a;011123123;*#

---

Appreciate the assitance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
// open your file and save to $txt
//$txt = "# 10 *1*100000190*1;Ice Cream; 15; 1;Coke; 8; 1;Chicken Burger; 33; *15*n/a;71; 4;John Doe;1 test street, City;insert time attribute; 184;7; n/a;011123123;*## 10 *1*100000191*1;Ice Cream; 15; 1;Chicken Wrap; 33; *15*n/a;63; 4;John Doe;1 test street, City;insert time attribute; 185;7; n/a;011123123;*## 10 *2*100000192*1;Chicken Wrap; 33; *0*n/a;33; 4;John Doe;1 test street, City;insert time attribute; 186;7; n/a;011123123;*#";
$txt = file_get_contents("yourfile");
$arr = preg_split("/#/", $txt);
$result = "";
foreach($arr as $line) {
    if(!empty($line)) {
        $components = preg_split("/\*/", $line);
        $orderNo = $components[2];
        if(checkIfWantToPrint($orderNo)) {
            // print and other operations
        } else {
            // add line
            $result .= "#".$line."#";
        }
    }
}
// save your file with $result value
file_put_contents("yourfile", $result);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. (Excuse if this is a silly question - I am still learning) How do I then delete that entire line if the order number( components[2] ) has already been checked and confirmed for deletion?

Comment: You can see in my full example that I have **if(checkIfWantToPrint($orderNo)) {**, so, you need implement **checkIfWantToPrint** function and return TRUE after print your order. It's all. If **checkIfWantToPrint** return TRUE, the line will be deleted (not added in the new file created)

Comment: Okay I see... I will give it a try and revert back. Thank you!

Comment: Excellent thank you! I can confirm that this works perfectly. Much appreciated.